# Skipping validation for closing the form from the controlbox

Tags: c#, winforms, validating-event

I have a simple form with a textbox and I want to make the user to enter some data in the textbox before closing or skipping this control,but when I handle  the validating event I 'm only able to close the form by putting a Cancel Button with CauseValidation property set to true.My question is that How can I enable the X button in control box for closing the form even when nothing is written in the textbox?By adding the form_closing handler,this button works the second time that I click it,but can I close the form by pressing the X button only once?

Here is my form.cs file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Validation
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
            {

                if(textBox1.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
                {
                e.Cancel=true;

                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1,"Error");

                }
                else
                    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1,"");
            }
       private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.CausesValidation = false;
        }
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, try this one.

```
  private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.CausesValidation)
            {
                textBox1.CausesValidation = false;
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you not satisfied with my answer because you not click that "as you a accepted answer". just kidding. welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Except the previous answer this method works too:

```
private void Input_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {


          e.Cancel = false;

        }
```